# Is it possible to slide only next when clicking on previous and next owl dots button?

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Clicking on previous owl dots sliding to previous it should slide to next.

I tried from `owl.min.js` but unable to catch the logic.

For example suppose the items of slides are 1,2,3.
Clicking on owl dots of 2 it will slide to 2 again clicking on previous owl dots instead of sliding to 1 it will slide to 3.